# How can mean value of a quantity $be$ an operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, hilbert-space, spherical-harmonics

In Laundau & Lifshitz *Quantum Mechanics. Non-relativistic theory* in $\S29$ a problem is given:

> **PROBLEM** Average the tensor $n_in_k-\frac13\delta_{ik}$ (where $\mathbf{n}$ is a unit vector along the radius vector of a particle) over a state where the magnitude but not the direction of the vector $\mathbf{l}$ is given (i.e. $l_z$ is indeterminate).

The solution then starts with this (italics mine):

> $\def\sc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
> \def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
> \sc{SOLUTION.}$ The required *mean value is an operator* which can be expressed in terms of the operator $\mathbf{\hat l}$ alone. We seek it in the form
>
> $$\overline{n_in_k}-\frac13\delta_{ik}=a[\hat l_i\hat l_k+\hat l_k\hat l_i-\frac23\delta_{ik}l(l+1)];$$
>
> this is the most general symmetrical tensor of rank two with zero trace that can be formed from the components of $\mathbf{\hat l}$. ...

What confuses me is the italicized part: "mean value is an operator". As I understand, mean value in a given state $|\psi\rangle$ of a quantity $\kappa$ is given by

$$\overline\kappa=\langle\psi|\hat\kappa|\psi\rangle.$$

Here $\overline\kappa$ is not an operator, but $\hat\kappa$ is. Do L&L try to abbreviate some clearer phrase by their statement? Or do I understand something wrongly?

Comment: Maybe they mean that this is an equivalent operator that acts in the space of fixed "$\ell$", spanned by states of different "m", from $-\ell$ to $\ell$?

Comment: @Ruslan - I looked in the book of Landau and Lifschitz. They explain you how to solve the exercise. Just I notice that in the end they give a formula in which appears $\hat {{\vec {\ell}}^2} = l(l+1)$. Of course, an operator is not equal to its eigenvalue. But what they do, given that you were told that the state $|\psi\rangle$is an eigenvalue of $\hat {{\vec {\ell}}^2}$, and given that they obtained that $\hat k$ in terms of $\hat {{\vec {\ell}}^2}$, they indeed do $\langle \psi|\hat k|\psi \rangle$, where $\hat k |\psi\rangle$ is replaced by the eigenvalue of $\hat k$ times$|\psi\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$\tag{1} \hat{T}_{ik}~:=~\hat{n}_i \hat{n}_k-\frac{1}{3}\delta_{ik}\hat{\bf 1}.$$

The phrasing of the problem in Ref. 1 is indeed not the clearest, but by comparing with the given solution, it seems that Ref. 1 is performing a partial averaging over the Hilbert space of states with fixed value of the orbital angular momentum quantum number $\ell$ and keeping the magnetic quantum number $m$ as a lone indeterminate. In practice, this means averaging over a radial direction.

In other words, Ref. 1 is considering an irreducible $(2\ell+1)$-dimensional representation $R$ of the operator algebra [and of the Lie group $SO(3)$], with a vector space $V$, spanned by vectors $|\ell m \rangle$, $m\in\{-\ell,\ldots,\ell\}$.
Denoting the averaging procedure with an overline, we have

$$\tag{2} \overline{\hat{T}_{ik}}~=~R(\hat{T}_{ik}), \qquad \hat{\ell}_i~:=~R(\hat{L}_i).$$

We would like to calculate the matrix elements

$$\tag{3}\langle \ell m | \overline{\hat{T}_{ik}}|\ell m^{\prime} \rangle 
~=~\langle \ell m |R(\hat{T}_{ik})|\ell m^{\prime} \rangle 
~=~f_{ik}(\ell,m,m^{\prime}), $$

which are some functions of $i,k,\ell,m,m^{\prime}$.
Instead of considering matrix elements, we may consider the operator/matrix $R(\hat{T}_{ik})\in{\rm End}(V)$. It is natural to assume that

$$\tag{4}R(\hat{T}_{ik})~=~\sum_{m,m^{\prime}}|\ell m \rangle\langle \ell m |R(\hat{T}_{ik})|\ell m^{\prime} \rangle\langle \ell m^{\prime} |
~=~\hat{f}_{ik}(\hat{\ell}_1,\hat{\ell}_2,\hat{\ell}_3;\ell).$$

It follows from the tensor structure that $R(\hat{T}_{ik})$ must be of the form

$$\tag{5}R(\hat{T}_{ik})~\propto~\{\hat{\ell}_i,\hat{\ell}_k\}_{+}-\frac{2}{3}\delta_{ik}\ell(\ell+1)\hat{\bf 1}.$$

See Ref. 1 for further details.

References:

1. L.D. Landau & E.M. Lifshitz, *QM,* Vol. 3, 3rd ed, 1981; $\S29$.

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite understand, over what we are averaging. As it is now, it seems $l$ is still a parameter of $\overline{\hat T_{ik}}$. As I understood the procedure, it's something like switching to a basis where $\hat T_{ik}$ is block-diagonal, picking one of these blocks (irreps) $R_l(\hat T_{ik})$, expressing it in terms of $R_l(\hat L_i)$, and then going back to original basis. Is it right?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's a bit clearer. So, does "averaging over a radial direction" actually mean "averaging over radial quantum numbers", like here $$\langle lm|\overline{\hat T_{ik}}|lm'\rangle=\sum_n\langle nlm|\hat T_{ik}|nlm'\rangle?$$ Or do you actually mean an integral over configuration space _direction_ $r$? (Or maybe it's somehow the same, and I'm confusing something?)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I did not read the question very clearly. I leave my old answer below as it answers directly the title and therefore may help future comers.

This does appear to be slightly sloppy language (though I wouldn't necessarily blame it on L&L if it's not present in the Russian original, but my Spanish copy has an equivalent form).I would read the text as

> The required mean value is *that of* an operator which can be expressed in terms of the operator $\mathbf{\hat l}$ alone.

This is indeed a correct statement, though you need fairly clunky machinery for it. The wavefunction $\psi(\mathbf r)$ can be split into an $r$-dependent part and a wavefunction on the unit sphere. The components $n_i$ are equal to spherical harmonics on the sphere, which means that they are a function of the components of angular momentum. Their product is therefore in the algebra, but since it transforms in a specific way it is reduced to the combinations claimed by L&L.

Their equation

> $$\overline{n_in_k}-\frac13\delta_{ik}=a[\hat l_i\hat l_k+\hat l_k\hat l_i-\frac23\delta_{ik}l(l+1)]$$

definitely has operators on both sides, so I think it's fairly safe to put this one to a language (or even translation) quirk.

---

**Any complex number can be seen as an operator.**

More specifically, any complex number $z$ acts on states $|\psi\rangle\in\mathcal H$ in a natural way via scalar multiplication: 
$$|\psi\rangle\mapsto z|\psi\rangle.$$
This operator is the natural embedding of $z$ into the space of linear operators on $\mathcal H$. As Landau and Lifshitz note, this is simply $z$ times<sup>1</sup> the identity operator $\mathbf 1$, which sends any $|\psi\rangle$ to itself.

There's really not much more to it. You're just applying this general concept to the specific complex number $\overline\kappa\in\mathbb C$.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Where "times", of course, is the scalar multiplication in $\mathcal L(\mathcal H)$ when it is seen as a vector space.</sup>

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  regretfully, this is not the issue, see my remark. The book indeed, was a bit non-rigorous and equated an operator with its eigenvalue.